# HorizontalScroll Image on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new at developing app and I'm trying to do my first app on Android Studio.
I have a problem: I would like that my horizontal scroll targets immediatly the next image (I will leave the photo)
[This is the first image that we see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COLeL.png)

After that photo, there is another one: 
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU3xO.png)
You can see that it shows both image 1 and image 2 together and I would like that it shows just 1 image at a time.

Tell me if the question is clear and if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Set One Image At a Time After Time Click The Second Image Is Popup Using The **Image Slider**

For Image Slider You Use With ViewPager